# get int from number in char *buffer

Tags: c++, c

How can I convert a number char in a buffer to an int.

I use:

```
char *buffer = somebuffer;
int number;
number = int(buffer[i]); // pointer to a number stored as a char
```

However, this returns the decimal code (e.g. if `buffer[i] = '2'`, `number = 50`).

How can I interpret this char number as an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract your char code from the character code for `0` (character codes for numbers are sequential and run from 0 (ascii 48) - 9 (ascii 57)).  Be sure to use `isdigit` first to check the char isn't outside the range `'0'` - `'9'`

```
int num = 0;
if (isdigit(buffer[i]) {
    num = buffer[i] - '0';
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily an ASCII code. Use the word "character code" instead.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks, (hopefully) now corrected

Comment: @simonc Thanks, I'm already using isdigit(). But your answer worked!